# How to handle this error : Class App\Http\Controllers\post/ProductController does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

Code in the blade file is given as below:

```
@extends('clientlayout.layouts.master1')
@section('title')
Register
@endsection
@section('content')
<div class="container" style="background-color: #c1bdba;max-width: 100% 
!important;">
<div class="row">
  <div class="offset-lg-2 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-8 border rounded main- 
  section"  style="background-color:rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);">
  <img src="client/images/decksys.png" alt="." style="margin: 20px 0px 20px 
350px;"> 
    <hr>
    <form class="container" action="/create" id="needs-validation" 
method="post" novalidate>
    <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token(); 
 ?>">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-inverse custom" 
 for="validationCustom01">First Name
 <span class="req">*</span>
 </label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" 
id="validationCustom01"  placeholder="First name"
value="" required maxlength="25" onKeyPress="return ValidateAlpha(event);" 
style="background-color: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.4); color:#fff;">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Enter Your Firstname
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div> 
 </form>
   </div>
   </div>  
   </div>
   @endsection
```

The Controller code is shown below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DarthSoup\Whmcs\Facades\Whmcs;
use Darthsoup\Whmcs\WhmcsServiceProvider;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
 public function insertform(){
    return view('clientlayout.main.signup');
    } 

  public function insert(Request $request){

    $user = User::create([
        'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'city' => $data['city'],
        'dob' => $data['dob'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
    Whmcs::create($data->all());
    return redirect($this->create());

    echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
    echo '<a href = "/insert">Click Here</a> to go back.';

    }

    }
```

The route code is given below and suggest me if any changes has to be made in the route.

```
Route::get('insert', 'ProductController@insertform');
Route::post('create','post/ProductController@insert');
```

Suggest me a solution to handle this error - "Product Controller doesn't Exit" and to get the output as follows:

> Record inserted successfully

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within your route declaration:

```
Route::get('insert', 'ProductController@insertform');
Route::post('create','post/ProductController@insert');
```

You don't need the `post/` in the second line, because the route is already created as `POST` route by calling `Route::post(...)`. So you should get it to work with:

```
Route::get('insert', 'ProductController@insertform');
Route::post('create','ProductController@insert');
```

---

Could also be that the paths you are using throughout your application are not correct (i.e. `/create` as your form action). You can assign a route name to your routes and use this instead:

```
Route::post('create', 'ProductController@insert')->name('product.create');

<form class="container" action="{{ route('product.create') }}"
      id="needs-validation" method="post" novalidate>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works correctly.. And can you give me an idea for posting the data entered during registration in the WHMCS.

Comment: Not sure if I can follow you. In your controller you are creating a `User` and a `Whmcs`. And after they are created, you want to display them? Well then you'd need something like: `$whmcs = Whmcs::create($data->all()); return redirect()->route('whmcs.detail', ['id' => $whmcs->id]);` or instead of the route, you can also display a view: `return view('whmcs.detail', ['whmcs' => $whmcs]);`. -- The two `echo` statements that come after the return are useless, by the way.